# Can i undo changes made in a row in issue log?

Tags: workflow

I updated a column with my comments by mistake and saved. How can i undo that row in sharepoint under issue log?

Comment: do you have versioning enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you do have versioning turned on: go to the context menu that pops up when you click to the right of the issue title to visit the version history. Then, on the version history window, hover over the date of the version you want to restore.. you'll get another ECB menu where you choose 'Restore'